# addClass() function not working after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
 $("#uname").keyup(function()
 {  
  var name = $(this).val(); 
  if(name.length > 3)
  {  
   $("#result").html('checking...');
   $.ajax({ 
    type : 'POST',
    url  : '<?php echo base_url('users/check') ?>',
    data : $(this).serialize(),
    success : function(data)
        {
              $("#result").html(data);
              $("#check").addClass("has-error"); // this doesn't seem to work
           }
    });
    return false;

  }
  else
  {
   $("#result").html('');
  }
 }); 
});
```

The AJAX response was working successfully, except `addClass()` function does not work, I want to add class `.has-error` to Bootstrap input class on this:

```
<div id="#check" class="form-group col-lg-6">
  <label>Username</label> <span id="result"></span>
    <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="form-control" id="" value="">
</div>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the id of in your markup. You have an extra `#`

```
<div id="check" class="form-group col-lg-6">
```

When you use a Id jQuery selector, it will be the in the format `'#'+theIdOfTheDomElement`. If you have an extra `#` as the prefix character of your dom element id attribute value, It will not work. So even if you try `$("##check").addClass("has-error");`, This will not work.

So remove the extra `#` prefix from the id attribute value.

***It is not just the prefix character.If you have `#` in anywhere in the id attribute value, It will not work  when you use the Id selector.***

i also see 2 instances of `id` attributes in your `uname` input element. You probably want to fix that as well.

Comment: working perfect. thank you..